# Statements about $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, the ring of Gaussian integers

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ be the rings of Gaussian integers. Then which of  the following statements are true:

a) if $P$ is a prime ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, then $\mathbb{Z}[i]/P$ is a field.

b) if $P$ is a prime ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, then $\mathbb{Z}[i]/P$ is always a degree 2 extension of its prime fields.

c) for any prime $p \in \mathbb{Z}$, the ideal $P$ generated by "$p$" in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is a prime ideal.

d) for any non zero prime ideal $P$ in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, the intersection $\mathbb{Z} \cap P$ is a non zero ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$.

I think option (c) is coprrect

Comment: Why do you think that (c) is correct, but others are not? Can you please add some of your own work and/or thought? Then it will be easier for the others to answer your question.

Comment: a) and b) are seen to be false from a detail mentioned in d)

Answer (score 0):

a) Consider $P=(0)$

b) Consider $P=(0)$

c) Try $p=2$ and consider what "prime ideal" would imply for $(1+i)\cdot (1-i)=2$.

d) Let $a+bi\in P\setminus\{0\}$. What can you say about $(a+bi)\cdot(a-bi)$?